# Saving Table of Int Arrays

Tags: linq

I have a Table full of players. Each of these players can have a list of Items that they own. What I need to do is store that list of items for each player. Each item has an ID which is unique.

What I want to do is store an array of these items as a field in the Player Table. Does anyone know how this could be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either go database route and create table of "ItemId to PlayerId" and query all items for given player by ID.

Or you can serialize data in XML/byte array using default .Net serialization and than dump it in BLOB field of "playerId to PlayerBLOB" table (XML/text can also be stored as text field - will be more readable).

Comment: Yes, create another table.  Do not store an array in one field, it will be really awkward to work with.

Comment: Thanks, both of you, I have figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can store it as a delimited text. BUT! store it as xml instead, this will allow you to store complex weapon list and configuration in a column.